# Long run data wire

Tags: led, wires

I need to connect the data of a LED strip (WS2812) to a pin but the strip is 10 meters away using AWG 22.
I use a 12V DC power supply.
Should I expect some misbehaviour, like the LED not getting the right color ?
If so, what could I do ?

Comment: What kind of LED strip? What gauge wire? How are you powering it? What signals does it use? etc, etc...

Comment: Is the power supply with the LED strip or the Arduino?

Comment: What kind of environment are you in?

Comment: Both, in a parallel circuit

Comment: It can't  be, unless you are bending the fabric of space-time.

Comment: The cables coming out my 12 dc transformer who is plug into 220V plug are divided into 2 branches, one for the arduino the other to the LED sttrip

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to power the LED strip from 12V then you can expect all the LEDs to explode. The WS2812 LEDs require 5V, not 12V.

If you have a large number of WS2812 in your strip, and you are powering them from the Arduino's 5V, then you can expect the Arduino to get extremely hot and go into thermal shutdown, or the voltage regulator to melt.

If you are in a noisy environment (electrically) then you can expect the data to get corrupted over that kind of distance.

What you should do:

1. Provide 5V to the LED strip from a power supply or regulator that can cope with the amount of current your LED strip needs.
2. Have another small Arduino next to the LED strip to drive the LEDs and communicate with that Arduino from your master Arduino through a suitable serial protocol that can cope with longer distance communications, or a wireless system.

Comment: LED strip has buck regulator, I could not have a 5V supply due to voltage drop so decided to have 12v and a LDO regulator. I unfortunatly cannot put any arduino near the LED strip, oonly small components

Comment: How small? You can get some pretty small Arduino boards...

Comment: Something as big as an ATtiny

Comment: I'm sure you could fit an ESP8266 in there if you tried...

Comment: Point of load regulation is a good idea, but you probably want a switching regulator not a linear one unless it is a short LED strip.  An ATtiny may be sufficient, and plenty of other processors including the ATmega come in small packages, the real question is where you LED patterns come from - program logic, an SPI flash, and sdcard, an external signal?  Of course you can also use a `line driver` and `line receiver` to accommodate a lengthy wire run between the MCU and the first LED.

Comment: I'm using 1 meter 60 Leds and planning on using internal memory of a controller with neopixel library. Line driver and receiver seems to be interesting could you  elaborate ?